# how to get column from third table with sql

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT m.*,p.place_title
                FROM members_meetings mm,meetings m,places p
                WHERE mm.meeting_id=m.meeting_id AND mm.member_id=$member_id AND m.cat_id=$cat_id AND m.place_id=p.place_id AND m.meeting_status<>0
                ORDER BY mm.meeting_id DESC";
```

---

I have another table meeting_time_poll containing these columns :

```
poll_id
meeting_id
poll_closed
poll_dates
poll_times
```

I need the poll_id where  meeting_time_poll.meeting_id=meeting.meeting_id 
How can I put it in the sql?

**Note:** not all meeting_id from table meeting have a corresponding in meeting_time poll

Comment: did you wrote `$sql` query? If yes, then you should know your answer..

Comment: it's part of php code my friend

Comment: `SELECT m.*,p.place_title.......` are part of PHP?? That is sql statement...

Comment: how can i put the new column in this sql statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$sql = "SELECT m.*,p.place_title, mp.poll_id
            FROM 
                members_meetings mm,
                meetings m,places p, 
                meeting_time_poll mp
            WHERE 
                mm.meeting_id=m.meeting_id
                AND mm.member_id=$member_id 
                AND m.cat_id=$cat_id 
                AND m.place_id=p.place_id 
                AND m.meeting_status<>0 
                AND mp.meeting_id=m.meeting_id
            ORDER BY mm.meeting_id DESC";
```

Also I would suggest using `JOIN`.

Comment: i still get repeated values i don't know why